How to use function on google sheet to gain result from match multiple criteria
Thank you for having a look at this question, all data shown are examples and not real datas.
I have the following datasheet named "Club" for :



DAY
TIME
CLUB
Last Name
First Name




THURSDAY
AFTER SCHOOL
Art Club
Le
John


THURSDAY
AFTER SCHOOL
Art Club
Lo
Amelia


THURSDAY
AFTER SCHOOL
Art Club
Gong
Jo


THURSDAY
AFTER SCHOOL
Art Club
Zhang
Messiah


THURSDAY
AFTER SCHOOL
Art Club
Lang
Kevin


MONDAY
LUNCHTIME
Colouring
Wang
Maria


MONDAY
LUNCHTIME
Colouring
Tian
Brendan


MONDAY
LUNCHTIME
Colouring
Liang
Sam


MONDAY
LUNCHTIME
Colouring
Wang
Lam



This continues for about 500 lines.











Monday
Monday
Monday
Tuesday
Tuesday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Wednesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Thursday
Thursday
Friday
Friday
Friday




Last Name
First Name
Tutor Group
Year Group
Gender
Medical Conditions/Dietary Needs
Parental Consents
Special Needs
BEFORE SCHOOL
LUNCHTIME
AFTER SCHOOL
BEFORE SCHOOL
LUNCHTIME
AFTER SCHOOL
BEFORE SCHOOL
LUNCHTIME
AFTER SCHOOL
BEFORE SCHOOL
LUNCHTIME
AFTER SCHOOL
BEFORE SCHOOL
LUNCHTIME
AFTER SCHOOL


Wango
Maria
Tiger
R
Female


No


















I am trying to both match the First Name and Last name, as well as the Day and the time, so four criteria matching.
I had the function for I3=INDEX(Club!C$2:C$564,MATCH(1,(B3=Club!E$2:E$564)*(A3=Club!D$2:D$564),0))
This functions works when its simply matching two criterias, but it output only the first result it find so I added more criterias :=INDEX(Club!C$2:C$564,MATCH(1,(B3=Club!E$2:E$564)*(A3=Club!D$2:D$564)*(J$1=Club!A$2:A$564)*(J$2=Club!B$2:B$564),0))
However this seems to yield #N/A.
I have yet to find a function that could do it or I am not even sure if this is possible, but if anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your kindness in advance

You may use Table to Markdown Generator to make tables as markdown and post them in questions. It's really helpful if you add data easy to copy/paste to replicate your problem. Also, I suggest you choose Excel OR Google Sheets. They may look the same but they are not the same program so choose 1

In Excel you can use the FILTER function. Also, please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?. Also decide which program you want to use: Sheets or Excel, and edit your tags appropriately.

Hi, Apologise for that pictures, I wasn't aware and I have converted them to tables. I have amended the title and tags to google sheet only.

Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the expected/desired result? Can you share a sample of how you are expecting the result to look in a sheet?

You can perform a multi condition lookup using VLOOKUP with concatenated search key and lookup column. Try the following formula in I3:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A&B3:B&I1:1&I2:2,{Club!D2:D&Club!E2:E&Club!A2:A&Club!B2:B,Club!C2:C},2,0)))

This formula fills the whole range I3:ZZZ so you don't have to drag it or copy it to the other cells.

This is an absolute amazing answer, and an amazing use of the VLOOKUP function, I never really knew this can be worked like this.

Can't beleive how simple the compoenent of the codes are, when I have enough reputation I will come back and upvote it, thanks again. Amazing talent at work, wow.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.
